# Python: Convert tuple of arrays to 2d array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I have the following:

```
  CCM = ([
       [1.06301910149183, 0.00722151174898679, -0.0646501819773272], 
       [0.0343462908139148, 0.93978476472001, 0.016122360796017],
       [0.000718294712585651, 0.0672092385672176, 0.867165723476061]
    ],)
```

and I want to convert it to :

```
  CCM = [
        [1.06301910149183, 0.00722151174898679, -0.0646501819773272], 
        [0.0343462908139148, 0.93978476472001, 0.016122360796017], 
        [0.000718294712585651, 0.0672092385672176, 0.867165723476061]
    ]
```

I have tried the following:

```
    ccm = list(CCM)
    CCM = [list(item) for item in ccm]
```

But I am getting:

```
CCM=[[
    [1.06301910149183, 0.00722151174898679, -0.0646501819773272], 
    [0.0343462908139148, 0.93978476472001, 0.016122360796017], 
    [0.000718294712585651, 0.0672092385672176, 0.867165723476061]
]]
```

Which is not what I want.

Thank you

Comment: What does `CCM[0]` give you?

Comment: Also, do you need a `list` or `np.ndarray` as output? if `numpy` array, try `np.array(CCM[0])`.

Comment: Unbelievable :-) CCM[0] works perfect